# Is there any program to root my device without connecting it to PC?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rooting

I am looking for an APK software which could be installed on my Android device (Samsung S3 I9300) that root my device without needing to connect the device to PC during root process. Or any other way for rooting without need of connecting to PC. Is there any way?

Comment: Android version is 4.0.4

Answer (score 3):

Framaroot, if you are running 4.2.2 or lower. I don't know about anything for 4.3 and up which works reliably on most devices.